# Why some functions have a derivative only at one point?

Tags: calculus

My name is Marcos Castillo, I was born and live in the city of Bilbao, near to the Spanish-French border; I am 56 years old, and discovered my passion for Physics two years ago. My background is High School and a career translated, or, better said, thoght to work in Marketing, Advertisements, etc. My level of English is Cambridge Certificate Grade B.

I would like to prove why this function has got a derivative only at $x=3$. I am a Physics undergraduate, in Spain, enrolled in Analysis, and this question keeps me wondering, because it involves the main concepts of the subject: continuity, discontinuity, differentiability...It is a question that any beginner at analysis must face correctly.

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}{x^2}&\text{if}& x\in \mathbb Q\\6(x-3)+9 & \text{if}& x\in \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q\end{cases}$$

Here is the proof:

1- $f(x)$s differentiable at $3$ if this limit exists:

$$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 3}{}\dfrac{f(x)-f(3)}{x-3}$$

This limit turns into two:

$$\displaystyle\lim_{x\in \Bbb Q,\,x \to 3}{}\dfrac{x^2-9}{x-3}$$

$$\displaystyle\lim_{x\in \Bbb I,\,x \to 3}{}\dfrac{6(x-3)+9-9}{x-3}$$

And both be equal.

The key to solve relais on considering $g:\Bbb D\to \Bbb R$, $D=A\cup B$ and take this two restrictions:

$$g_1:\Bbb A\to \Bbb R,\quad g_1(x)=g(x)$$
$$g_2:\Bbb B\to \Bbb R,\quad g_2(x)=g(x)$$

Such that:

$$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to a}{}g_1(x)=\displaystyle\lim_{x \to a}{}g_2(x)=L$$

Hence:

$$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to a}{}g(x)=L$$

$$\displaystyle\lim_{x\in \Bbb Q,\,x \to 3}{}\dfrac{x^2-9}{x-3}=6$$

For $x \in\Bbb Q$, $\forall{\varepsilon}$ $\exists\;{\delta_1}$ such that $$0<|x-3|<\delta_1\Rightarrow{\left |{\dfrac{x^2-9}{x-3}-6}\right |=|x+3-6|=|x-3|<\varepsilon}$$

Therefore, $\delta_1=\varepsilon$

$$\displaystyle\lim_{x\in \Bbb I,\,x \to 3}{}\dfrac{6(x-3)+9-9}{x-3}=6$$

For $x \in\Bbb R\setminus{\Bbb Q}$, $\forall{\varepsilon}$, $\exists\;{\delta_2}$ such that, if $$0<|x-3|<\delta_2\Rightarrow{\left |{\dfrac{(6(x-3)+9)-9}{x-3}-6}\right |=|6-6|=0<\varepsilon}$$.
Hence, $\delta_2$ can take any positive value, and the implication will be true.

If we pick $\delta_1=\varepsilon$, the more restrictive $\delta$, we prove that $f(x)$ has a derivative at $x=3$

2- Why is not continous if $x \neq 3$?

$$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to x_0,x\in \Bbb Q}{}x^2=x_0^2$$

Proof: If $$0<|x-x_0|<\delta\Rightarrow{|x^2-x_0^2|<\varepsilon}$$

$$|x^2-x_0^2|=|x-x_0||x+x_0|$$

We take a first restriction: $$|x-x_0|<1\Leftrightarrow{x_0-1<x<x_0+1}\rightarrow{|x+x_0|<2|x_0|+1}$$

Explanation:
$x_0 \in \Bbb Q\setminus{\{3\}}$:
$x_0-1<x<x_0+1$;
$2x_0-1<x+x_0<2x_0+1$;
Now, by the triangle inequality:
$|x+x_0|\leq{|x|+|x_0|<|x_0|<2|x_0|+1}$

Hence, for $\delta=\varepsilon/2|x_0|+1$ this limit exists.

$$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to x_0,x\in \Bbb I}{}(6(x-3)+9)=6x_0-9$$

Proof:

If $0<|x-x_0|<\delta\Rightarrow{|(6x-9)-(6x_0-9)|<\varepsilon}$

$$|6x-9-6x_0+9|<\varepsilon\Rightarrow{6|x-x_0|<\varepsilon}$$

For $\delta=\varepsilon/6$

and $x_0^2=6x_0-9$ if and only if $x_0=3$

Comment: First, notice that the function $f$ is not a polynomial on $\mathbb{R}$. If viewed only on $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$, it is a polynomial, indeed. But together, $f$ is not a polynomial. Before you can talk about differentiability, you require continuity. What are all the points where $f$ is continuous?

Comment: If I were you I'd start by looking at an easier example: $g(x)=x^2$ si $x\in\mathbb{Q}$, $g(x)=0$ otherwise; where is it continuous? where is it differentiable?

Answer (score 3):

Know your definitions:

$f$ is *continuous* at $x_0$ if $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=f(x_0)$

$f$ is *differentiable* at $x_0$ if $f'(x_0)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}$ exists.

If $f$ is *discontinuous*, $\lim_{h\to 0}f(x_0+h)\neq f(x_0)$ and hence $f$ is *not differentiable*.

The piecewise function given is continuous *only* where the two pieces are equal (because for every $x, y\in \Bbb Q$, we can find $z\in\Bbb R/\Bbb Q:x<z<y)$. In other words $x^2=6(x-3)+9\implies x=3$ (double root). Hence, the function may only be differentiable at $x=3$ (diff $\to$ cont, but the opposite is not always true). In this case, it is (simply check $f'(3)$ exists, for both piece functions it is equal to $6$)